# Laravel update single column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello am working in laravel crud and all are working fine except update. I need to update a single column of my database.The column i need to update is soldStatus.

Controller class.

```
public function update(Request $request, $product_id)
    {
        $request->validate([
         
            'product_sales_status'=>'required'
            
                         
        ]);
        $prod = Products::FindOrFail('product_id');
        $prod->product_id =  $request->input('product_id');
        $prod->product_sales_status =  $request->input('product_sales_status');
       
        $prod->save();
        return redirect()->back();


    }
```

Modal body with update form

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form action="{{route('products.update', $productt- 
      >product_id)}}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <p> Item will be registerd as Sold?</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_sales_status" value="Yes">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$productt->product_id}}">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</form>
```

and my route file is like below

```
Route::post('products_list/{product_id}','ProductsController@update')->name('products.update');
```

Thanks

Comment: what error .? your getting ?

Comment: $prod = Products::findOrFail('product_id');
$prod->soldStatus = true;
$prod->save();

Comment: #@Kamlesh Paul on my error nothing on Mohammed answer i got error Creating default object from empty value

Comment: This should work,  `$prod = Products::FindOrFail($product_id);` or `$prod = Products::FindOrFail($request->product_id');`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $product_id)
    {
        $request->validate([
         
            'product_sales_status'=>'required'
            
                         
        ]);
        $prod = Products::find($product_id);
        $prod->product_sales_status =  $request->input('product_sales_status');
        $prod->save();
        return redirect()->back();


    }
```

I think you wanna update `product_sales_status` column. However, you can change the column name in `$prod->product_sales_status`

Comment: i have tried this error comes Creating default object from empty value